# Remove the UItableview cell segue button?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I was just wondering if it was possible to remove the button that is automatically added to the UItableview cell when creating a segue in storyboard between the cell background and the destination view. For my app, it takes up to much space. I'd rather the user just tap any where on the cell to activate the segue.

Does anyone know how to do this? When I select the button in the cell and hit delete, the whole cell deletes.

Comment: What button are you taking about? If you make a segue from the cell, and choose "Selection Segue", no button is added.

Comment: I just tried this to no success. I go from the cell to the view and under "Selection Segue" I choose push. Then a button with an arrow appears on the cell on the right hand side. I should note incase it matters that I have another view that also segues to the destination view I want to go to,

Comment: Select on storyboard Atributes inspector and select the tablecell you don't want it to appear the Accesory and then select Accessory: none

Answer (score 1, accepted):

eddwinpaz answer is what worked for me (as I was using storyboard and not doing it with code)

"Select on storyboard Atributes inspector and select the tablecell you don't want it to appear the Accesory and then select Accessory: none"

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the following code to your cellForRowAtIndexPath method:

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
              cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
```